# Using Surf and Peaks for non square Matrices

Tags: matlab, matrix, mesh, surf

Im trying to use meshgrid with peak. When I use square matrices like:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(1:10,1:10)
z = peaks(10)
surf(x,y,z)
```

Everything works fine.

However, when I use Non square matrices:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(-30000:500:0,10:500); 
z = peaks(?)
surf(x,y,z)
```

Im getting the following error:

```
Data dimensions must agree.
```

Any idea how to make it work?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

When you plot a function using `surf` the variables you pass it must all be the same size. Although you are changing the `x` and `y` matrices to non-square matrices, you are not creating a correspondingly sized `z` matrix. If you look at the documentation for `peaks`, this [tells you](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/peaks.html)  that this function can only produce square outputs, which complicates things somewhat. I would suggest that you try to plot some other example function instead.

If you absolutely must plot the `peaks` function, you could use some kind of interpolation:

```
x = 1:10;
y = 1:10;
[x_mesh, y_mesh] = meshgrid(x,y);
z = peaks(10);

x2 = 1:0.1:10;
y2 = 1:0.5:10;
[x2_mesh, y2_mesh] = meshgrid(x2, y2);
z2 = interp2(x_mesh, y_mesh, z, x2_mesh, y2_mesh);

surf(x2_mesh, y2_mesh, z2);
```

This gives me the following plot:

[image: Peaks Plot]

Comment: I have managed to solve it by defining [x,y] = meshgrid(linspace(-30000,0,200),linspace(0,500,200)). This way both matrices are 200x200 and so does z.